# Camera permission Xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode

I need to access the camera. This used to be managed in the info.plist, but this file is not as it was. I have looked in `targets->Info` but I can't seem to find where to set the permission.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios. You need to add `NSCameraUsageDescription`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xcode 13, you edit the *Info.plist* by editing the app target and going into the Info pane. There you see a short list of keys and values. Add the privacy key for the camera.